# What am I doing wrong on try to save image in USerDefault

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I gotta get an image then save it to UserDefaults to be able to retrieve it. However, I tried by saving as UIImage but when I try to retrieve the image the app crashes. How would be the best way for me to do that?

***That's how I'm trying to save the picture.***

```
import UIKit

protocol dataReceivedDelegate {
    func dataReceived(fotoSaved:[UIImage],nameSaved:NSArray)
}

class adicionarNovoItemVc: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldNome: UITextField!
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    @IBOutlet weak var namePreview: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imagePreview: UIImageView!
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    var arrayName = [String]()
    var arrayFoto = [UIImage]()
    var delegate:dataReceivedDelegate? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textFieldNome.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: "namesSavedArray") == true{
            arrayName = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "namesSavedArray") as! [String]
        }
        if isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: "fotoSavedArray") == true{
            arrayFoto = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "fotoSavedArray") as! [UIImage]
        }
    }
    func isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: String) -> Bool {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) != nil
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.imagePreview.image = image
            self.namePreview.text = self.textFieldNome.text
        }
        self.picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.textFieldNome.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func botaoAdcItem(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (self.namePreview!.text != nil) && (self.imagePreview!.image != nil) {
            if delegate != nil {

                arrayName.append(self.namePreview.text!)
                arrayFoto.append(self.imagePreview.image!)

                delegate?.dataReceived(fotoSaved: arrayFoto, nameSaved: arrayName as NSArray)

                UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayName, forKey: "namesSavedArray")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayFoto, forKey: "fotoSavedArray")

            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
        else {return}
}
```

Comment: Do not store images in `UserDefaults`.

Comment: So, how I could do that instead? @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Duncan-c have said, you should not save it in UserDefaults. 
You can save the selected filename (URL) though in UserDefaults 
and load the actual image using the filename (URL) next time you want to use it.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
  if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as! URL? {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(imageURL, forKey: "SelectedImage")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
  }

  ...  
  picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

// Load the image
if let imageURL = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "SelectedImage") {
   if let data = NSData(contentsOf: imageURL) as NSData? {
      self. imagePreview.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't write `URL` objects to `UserDefaults`. The only legal object types you can write are `Data`, `String`, `NSNumber`, `Date`, `Array`, or `Dictionary`.

Comment: If it's  not allowed then why is the url function available from UserDefaults? If you think about it, it just a string.

Comment: A `URL` type is not just a string. It is a class with lots of properties and methods beyond `String`. And what do you mean "why is the url function available from UserDefaults"?

Comment: Oh, you are right. There is a convenience method to write a `URL` object to `UserDefaults`. Interesting.

Comment: Hello @ChristianAbella, thanks for helping me. However, I'm facing an error in view that I have to populate a UITableView with these images, I should save an array of URL, correct? Otherwise, how can I append new images without lost the previous images set before by the user?

Comment: Because every time the screen loads I gotta check if the userdefault key "SelectedImage" has any value (images already saved). If so, should move it to an Array then append another image wanted by the user. Finally, I save the userdefault once again, now containing another image. Did you get me?

Comment: Hello @DuncanC! Would have any solution for me facing what I said above?

Comment: you need an SQLite if you are storing that many.  I would recommend this library.  I have tried FMDB and SQLite.swift but this one offers the best support for concurrency:

https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift

Comment: SQLite might be overkill for a modest-sized array of strings that doesn't change that much. A plist file saved to the app's documents directory would work just fine.

Comment: Save an Array of URL paths to a property list file.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, and should not, store images to `UserDefaults`. `UserDefaults` is intended to hold short things like user inputted strings or preference settings.

It can only save a short list of data types ("property list" objects: Array, Dictionary, String, Data, Date, integer types, floating point types, or Bools). Any other data type will fail.

I suggest saving the image to the user's Documents directory and then saving a path to the file in `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for helping me. Could you give me an example on how to save the image to Documents directory, please?

Comment: Read the docs, break it in to steps, and see if you can figure it out. First challenge is to get a URL to the app's documents directory. Second challenge is to append the filename to the documents directory URL and getting a new URL object. Third challenge: Writing the image to the URL. Your search keys for the Xcode help system are `FileManager` and `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`