# How do i save an image as a userdefault in swift?

Tags: swift, image, userdefaults

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V2a4.png)

The code is:

```
@IBAction func CheckBoxTuesdayButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        
        
        
        if CheckBoxTuesday.image == UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "CheckmarkButtonPressed"){
            
            CheckBoxTuesday.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "CheckBoxButton")
               
            
        }
        else{
            
            CheckBoxTuesday.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "CheckmarkButtonPressed")
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(CIImage.self, forKey: "TuesdayChecked")
        }
```

I tried the Userdefault line of code but it said i couldnt convert it to NSuserdefault.

Comment: UserDefaults is not recommended for anything as large as an image. It's intended for small amounts of data like usernames. It would be better to save the image to a file in your app's documents directory and then save the pathname to the file into UserDefaults.

Comment: @DuncanC Good advice but I suggest that you only save the filename, not the pathname, since the path can change between runs of the app.

Comment: @NathanA 1) Besides the other suggestion, also note that you should not use the `setValue(_:forKey:)` method of UserDefaults. That's a carry-over from Objective-C and KVC. Use the documented `set(_:forKey:)` methods you see for `UserDefaults`. 2) Why are you passing in `CIImage.self` as the value you want to store? If you want to save something to user defaults, you need to pass in the actual value you wish to store.

Comment: @HangarRash good point. Filename or partial path is probably better than full path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What am I doing wrong on try to save image in USerDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256305/what-am-i-doing-wrong-on-try-to-save-image-in-userdefault)

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

Rather than saving the image associated with the checkbox, you should save a model object, some representation that captures which check boxes have been selected.

---

We often draw a distinction between the “model” (some structure that indicates which check boxes have been checked) from the “view” (which images are shown in which UI controls). So, you don’t really want to save the image in persistent storage at all, but rather some model structure that indicates which switches are at what state. Likewise, when toggling a control, you toggle the representation in your model, and then update the UI (and persistent storage) accordingly.

For example, it appears that you have switches for each of the days of the week. That might call for some model object that represented which switches are turned on and off. An [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) seems like a logical candidate:

```swift
struct Days: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let sunday     = Days(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let monday     = Days(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let tuesday    = Days(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let wednesday  = Days(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    static let thursday   = Days(rawValue: 1 << 4)
    static let friday     = Days(rawValue: 1 << 5)
    static let saturday   = Days(rawValue: 1 << 6)

    static let none: Days = []
    static let all: Days  = [.sunday, .monday, .tuesday, .wednesday, .thursday, .friday, .saturday]
}
```

And you might have some method on this type, `Days`, to toggle a particular day on and off:

```swift
extension Days {
    mutating func toggle(_ day: Days) {
        if contains(day) {
            remove(day)
        } else {
            insert(day)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you might have a property to store your model object to reflect what days are checked:

```swift
var selectedDays: Days = .none
```

And then the `@IBAction` might do something like:

```swift
@IBAction func didTapTuesday(_ sender: Any) {
    selectedDays.toggle(.tuesday)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedDays.rawValue, forKey: "days")
    tuesdayCheckBox.image = selectedDays.contains(.tuesday) ? .checked : .unchecked
}
```

(Forgive my changing of the names of this function and the properties as convention is to start method and variable names with a lowercase letter. We only use uppercase letters for type names, but methods and properties always start with a lowercase letter. But use whatever method/property names you want.)

Anyway, the images `checked` and `unchecked` might be defined like so:

```swift
extension UIImage {
    static var checked = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "CheckmarkButtonPressed")
    static var unchecked = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "CheckBoxButton")
}
```

And, of course, in `viewDidLoad`, you might call a function that fetches the value and updates all the controls:

```swift
func fetchDays() {
    let value = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "days")
    selectedDays = Days(rawValue: value)
    sundayCheckBox.image    = selectedDays.contains(.sunday)    ? .checked : .unchecked
    mondayCheckBox.image    = selectedDays.contains(.monday)    ? .checked : .unchecked
    tuesdayCheckBox.image   = selectedDays.contains(.tuesday)   ? .checked : .unchecked
    wednesdayCheckBox.image = selectedDays.contains(.wednesday) ? .checked : .unchecked
    thursdayCheckBox.image  = selectedDays.contains(.thursday)  ? .checked : .unchecked
    fridayCheckBox.image    = selectedDays.contains(.friday)    ? .checked : .unchecked
    saturdayCheckBox.image  = selectedDays.contains(.saturday)  ? .checked : .unchecked
}
```

---

So all of this cuts the Gordian knot, eliminating the very idea of storing the image in `UserDefaults` at all.

That having been said, I personally would not store any model data in `UserDefaults` (not even just this `Int` raw value). I would write it to persistent storage (in iOS 17, I might use Swift Data as outlined in WWDC 2023’s [Meet SwiftData](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10187/)). Or perhaps that’s overkill, then I might make `Days` a `Codable` type and write it to a JSON file in persistent storage.

Use `UserDefaults`, as shown in my code snippets above, if you really must. It is, admittedly, very convenient. But one should recognize that `UserDefaults` is intended for defaults/preferences, not for model data, and we would generally use one of these other storage mechanisms for model data.

---

Note, my model structure, `Days`, which is an `OptionSet`, is just one example of a possible model structure. There are lots of possible permutations on the idea. You might have a series of Booleans. Or you may get have some other structure to capture you model data (e.g., a `Set`, an `Array`, a custom `struct`, etc.). But the idea is the same: Have some model type that represents the logical data. But we would not generally use `UIImage` (unless the user was picking custom images from their photo library or camera).

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is not recommended. You are only supposed to save small snippets like user preferences.

If you are determined to do it anyway, you need to convert your data to one of the small number of "property list types" that UserDefaults supports.

They are, using their Objective-C names (With the Swift name in parens)

NSData (Data),
NSString (String),
NSNumber (Still NSNumber),
NSDate (Date),
NSArray (Array),
NSDictionary (Dictionary)

(NSNumber is an object wrapper for a scalar value. UserDefaults has helper functions that let you read/write scalar values like Int, Float, and Double.)

In your case you'd have to convert your image to `Data` and the save the `Data`. (But don't do that.)

### Edit:

Also note that there are various problems with your code. The line that attempts to save the image tries to save `CIImage.self` which is totally wrong.

In your case it looks like you are trying to save the state of a user's checkbox selection. Saving an image to remember a user's selection is silly. Create an enum with an Int raw value and save the rawValue to UserDefaults.

And your code that figures out what to save makes no sense either. That code is **riddled** with errors.

Comment: FYI - I just linked a duplicate that you answered years ago with the same basic suggestion. :)

Comment: That's pretty funny.

Answer (score -1):

Storing images in UserDefaults is not recommended, as it can reduce app performance and increase the size of the app's user defaults database. However, if you still need to store an image in UserDefaults, you can convert it to a **base64** string and store that instead.

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    func toBase64() -> String? {
        guard let data = pngData() else { return nil }
        return data.base64EncodedString()
    }
}

func saveBase64Image(image: UIImage, key: String) {
    if let base64Image = image.toBase64() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(base64Image, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why base64? You can store raw data in user defaults. Though, as you said, it's not a good idea. It's the wrong tool.

Comment: Why convert the image to Base64? You can save the image as Data. Base64 expands the size of the image by 25% (it only uses 6 of 8 bits.)

Comment: How do you store raw data in user defaults?

Comment: `extension UserDefaults {

    func saveData(data: Data, key: String) {
        set(data, forKey: key)
    }

    func retrieveData(key: String) -> Data? {
        return data(forKey: key)
    }

}`

Comment: @DuncanC AFAIR data will be stored as a base64 string anyway. I might be wrong but AFAIK data is always converted to base64 string when stored to a plist file.

Comment: @LeoDabus, it depends. If you save a plist in xml format, the data is converted to Base64. If you save it in binary format, it's left as full 8-bit binary. (As a result binary plists are faster and smaller than XML plists.) I'm not sure which format is used for UserDefaults.